# Unable to install testNG in eclipse - Getting error states could not find the URL 'https://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/'

Tags: testng

Unable to install testNG in eclipse -  Getting error states could not find the URL 'https://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/'

it seems the url is giving 404.

I have tried with different URLs

Answer (score 2):

Paste the url testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site (use https://) and press enter.

This is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

what steps you tried, from testng doc

```
  Select Help / Install New Software...
 Enter the update site URL in "Work with:" field:
 Update site for release: https://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/
 Make sure the check box next to URL is checked and click Next.
 Eclipse will then guide you through the process.
```

To be simple, Help > Install New Software > Add > provide TestNG in name and https://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/ in location > Add > select Check box once displayed > Next ....

Comment: I am following the same method only but this is not working for me, still getting this error- 'Could not find https://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/'  Is there any change in this URL